# const initialisation with C++

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

What is the difference in terms of the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int get_value(int value){
   return 3 * value;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{ 

   const int a = 5;
   const int b = get_value(4);


   return 0;
}
```

Is the only difference that const int a is stored in the bss section and that const int b is not and both are still enforced in terms by the compiler.

Thus since a in stored in the bss is it faster? as const in a is compile time computed, is this the use case for constexpr? would constexpr make const in b stored in the bss section?

Blair

Comment: The language says nothing about the layout of the final executable; it would be perfectly valid for the compiler to dynamically allocate both of those and ensure they're automatically freed (this is where "automatic" in "automatic storage duration" comes from). Of course, doing this would be wasteful and very stupid. If you're concerned about this, refer to your compiler's documentation and look at the output.

Comment: In contrast to GManNickG's answer, it would also be perfectly acceptable for the compiler to optimize away both variables so that they weren't stored anywhere. GManNickG is right the only way to answer this question is to examine the output of your compiler/linker. The C++ language says nothing about these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have included constexpr tag in your question I assume you can use C++11 constexpr, so you could change your function to `constexpr int get_value(constexpr int value);` and then use the function like `constexpr int b = get_value(4);`. This will ensure that the calculation will be done at compile time, and b can be optimised out by a compiler like a preproccessor constant. However if anywhere in you program, you get a pointer to b (e.g. `int* p = &b`), `b` is not optimised and therefore is stored in memory at runtime.